# jQuery calculation & selecting

Tags: jquery

> Hello

I'm trying to learn jQuery, got me some books: jQuery from novice to the ninja. Trying to learn as much as possible.

I try to do a little calculation app that calculates the merit of elementary school students.

To the effect that students will choose a rating of 18 subject, but two are removed. One can choose between four different grades.

no rating, you get: zero points.
A: you get 20 points.
B: you get 15 points.
C: you get 10 points.

The algorithm:
If a student gets to 15 A and three other C so count it out as follows:
15 x 20 = 300 points
3 x 10 = 30 points.
A total of 18 topic = 330 points.
But two of the smallest value scores must be removed for it to be correct. Thus two of the C-rating. So then, merit rating:
15 x 20 = 300 points
3 x 10 = 30 Points
- 2 x of the minimum scores = 2 x 10 = 20 points.
The final answer is = 310points.

I do not really know how I should proceed to select all the radio boxes and perform calculations. How should I think and how should I go about it.

I have helped with some html code that is a bit quickly written, hope you bear with the basic html code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Merit rating</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Merit rating is the sum of the 16 best in your grades.</h1>
    <p>A: 20 points</p>
    <p>B: 15 points</p>
    <p>C: 10 points</p>
    <p>Not rated: 0 points</p>

    <p><strong>The highest score you can get is 320 which means that it has Distinction in all subjects.</strong></p>
    <p>Do you have 17 or 18 scores, you remove one or two of the worst grade, your meritis made up of your 16 best scores.</p>

    <div id="Grade">
        <p><strong>Swedish:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                    <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                    <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                    <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>English:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClassEnglish" value="20"/>A
                    <input type="radio" name="radClassEnglish" value="15"/>B
                    <input type="radio" name="radClassEnglish" value="10"/>C
                    <input type="radio" name="radClassEnglish" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Mathematics:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Religion:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Social Studies:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>History:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Geography:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Chemistry:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Physics:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Biology:</strong><input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Technology:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Picture class:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Home economics:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Music:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Sports and Health:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>HandCraft:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Language:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <p><strong>Student Choice:</strong> <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="20"/>A
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="15"/>B
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="10"/>C
                        <input type="radio" name="radClass" value="0"/>Not rated
        </p>
        <input type="button" id="calcButton" value="Calculate"/><p id="answer"></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code so far, remove the details of how your applications works, and ask specifically what you need help with, I.E Selecting Check Boxes, Calculating from the array etc.

Comment: Sorry I am new here.. but I have edit the code now

Answer (score 1):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/gx6TM/1/

```
$('#calcButton').click(function() {
    var sum = 0,
        arr = [];

    // put the values into an array
    $('input:radio:checked', '#Grade').each(function() {
        var value = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        if ( !isNaN(value) ) { arr.push(value); }
    });

    // sort the array numerically and ascending
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a - b;
    });

    // delete the first two array items (the lowest two scores)
    arr = arr.slice(2);

    // calculate the sum
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i]; 
    }

    // print the sum on the page
    $('#answer').text(sum);    
});
```

Note that you also have to set the radio button name attributes so that each radio button group has a distinct name.

Comment: I guess you should remove those zero values too, that is when one of it is not rated.

Comment: @Reigel You mean the value attributes of the last radio buttons in each row?

Comment: Thanks alot Sime! I have to check out some of the function you have write to understand the code better. ^^